# BI Publisher in Word SUM

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft, bi-publisher

Please note the following data:

- COMP - 416.00
- DEVC - 16.00
- DEVE - 32.00
- ELEC - 64.00
- YCL - 32.00

In Word I created a field with the following properties:

```
<?for-each:SSR_AIR_PARM?><?if:SSR_ENRL_CAT!='DEVC'?><?if:SSR_ENRL_CAT!='DEVE'?><?MIN_UNITS_REQD?><?end if?><?end if?><?end for-each?>
```

It gives the correct:

- 416
- 64
- 32

How do I sum that instead of putting out the three values?

ie. `<?sum( 416, 64, 32 )?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?sum(SSR_AIR_PARM[SSR_ENRL_CAT!='DEVC' and SSR_ENRL_CAT!='DEVE']/MIN_UNITS_REQD)?>
```

should also give the required answer,without a for loop, and without a variable. You can give the searchspec in those square brackets at the node level,and [sum](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10091_01/doc/bip.1013/b40017/T421739T481157.htm) up the element under that node which meet the search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out. For those interested:

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’, 0)?><?for-each:SSR_AIR_PARM?><?if:SSR_ENRL_CAT!='DEVC'?><?if:SSR_ENRL_CAT!='DEVE'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’, xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’) + MIN_UNITS_REQD)?><?end if?><?end if?><?end for-each?>
```

Then later I just used:

```
<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’)?>
```

To retrieve the total.